# Should swagger UI be a different application

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am currently battling a swagger configuration for my spring MVC RESTful services project. I decided to follow the [swagger-spring](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc) but I fail to understand if the UI part of swagger should be a totally different project or should it reside in the same context on the container?

The swagger json from my spring mvc based RESTFul services is showing up correctly on a link like: `http://<server>:<port>/<context>/api-docs` but whenever I put in the swagger UI components in the application(JSP, CSS and JS files), I cannot access the swagger UI, which should look like [this](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update index.html that came with swagger-ui. Update below line to your webapp URL.

url: "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs",

Comment: Thanks for the response phoenix2010, but my question was whether the swagger UI code reside in the RESTFul services application or should it be a separate application. I understand that whatever be the case, index.html needs to be updated with my services URL.

Comment: It can be a different app. Swagger-ui uses /api-docs as a starting point and crawls to all the available API. As swagger-ui OOB is able to get all the API's at "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/" supoorts the statement. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks phoenix2010. Appreciate your response.